# i have an array in an array that contains 3 items, how do I make it go through every item in both arrays?

Tags: php, ldap

I am pulling results from an LDAP query with php.  One of the items in the array of results is an array with 3 sets of information.  How do I make it display all three sets instead of just the first?  See my code below:

```
        if ($ds) {     $ds=ldap_connect("ldap-server");  

            $r=ldap_bind($ds);     
            $sr=ldap_search($ds, "DC=,DC=co,DC=uk",$search);  
            $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr)or die('get info fail');
            $header = array(
                t('Picture'),
                t('First Name'),
                t('Last Name'),
                t('Role'),
                t('Email')
            );
            $rows = array();
            for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
                //Handle Image
                if(isset($info[$i]["jpegphoto"][0])){
                    $tempFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'image');
                    file_put_contents($tempFile, $info[$i]["jpegphoto"][0]);
                    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
                    $mime  = explode(';', $finfo->file($tempFile));
                    $jpeg = '<img src="data:' . $mime[0] . ';base64,' . base64_encode($info[$i]["jpegphoto"][0]) . '"/>';
                }else{
                    $path = drupal_get_path('module','search_engine');
                    $jpeg = '<img src="'.$path.'/images/userImage.jpg" />';
                }
                $rows[$i] = array(
                    'picture'   => $jpeg,
                    'first'     => $info[$i]["givenname"][0],
                    'last'      => $info[$i]["sn"][0],
                    'role'      => $info[$i]["memberof"][0],
                    'mail'      => $info[$i]["mail"][0],
                );

            }
            ldap_close($ds);
return theme('table', array('header'=>$header,'rows'=>$rows));
```

I'm showing picture, first, last, role, and email in my table.  Role contains an array with 3 items, how do I make it go through every item in the array?  I know I can't just throw a foreach into the middle of an array.

I need to display all of these.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to do anything with the individual roles in that sub-array, e.g. display it only, then simply `implode()` it into a string:

```
$rows[$i] = array(
   ...
   'roles' => implode(',', $info[$i]['memberof'])
   ...
);
```

If you do need do some with the individual components, then deal with it separately:

```
$rows[$i] = array(...normal non-array data here);

foreach($info[$i]['memberof'] as $key => $value) {
   $rows[$i]['role'][$key] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [implode()](https://www.php.net/function.implode)?

```
$roles = array("role1","role2","role3");
$imploded = implode(",", $roles);
echo $imploded; //should return "role1,role2,role3"
```